# Merge overlapping, differently sized faces in large model

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, faces

I have a code-generated model that has a lot of very regular but overlapping geometry. I am looking for a method to automate merging faces that share so much geometry, and overlap. In some cases there are 5-6 faces that pass through the same edge intersections. Everything in this model is at right angles, and it all points in the right direction. (Essentially a huge collection of rectangles, some nested in others creating this face/edge overlap)

I've tried tools in blender (self-intersect knife cut, merge by distance etc.) and out (Meshlab)

But there seems to be no good way to achieve this?

The red highlights below are not vertices, just edges on different planes.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108691/create-vertex-at-intersecting-edges

Comment: If you are referring to the tinycad suggestion, I have already tried that. There are roughly 40 thousand faces, most of them have more than one interaction like above. Tiny cad only allows this to be edited one edge/edge intersection at a time.

Comment: Not particularly. I was referring to a possible solution here is adding verts at edge intersections and remove doubles. The link posted is a dupe, the dupe has 7 answers. There are also links mentioned in comments.  If you have tried something and it doesn't work please edit relevant info into question.

Comment: I listed the promising methods I tried in the initial post. The problem with adding verts at intersections is that there doesn't seem to be an automated way of doing that?